# truffle migrate Error

Tags: migrate, ethereum, truffle

I can´t  migrate the standart contracts that come with truffle init. Here´s what i do:

```
truffle init
truffle compile
truffle migrate
```

and this is what it generates when i init:

[image]

But when i migrate , the following list of errors shows up:

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:115:32)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:544:12)
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:414:24)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:309:9)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
```

Comment: make sure your testrpc sever is running and check your truffle.js config has the right port and ip address.

Comment: thank you, the port and adress were correct i just forgot to testrpc before all this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As webjunkie comments:

1. `testrpc`
2. Check your truffle.js config port and ip is set to default 'localhost:8545'
3. `truffle migrate`

Answer (score 1):

For Solidty To Migrate, The Local Ethereum Blockchain should be running already and the Smart Contract you want to migrate should go to the correct Local Ethereum Blockchain so you need to check the Port Number of the Local Ethereum Blockchain.

1. `ganache-cli` or `testrpc` (For Making a local Blockchain). It has the port number on which it is running written beneath. Such as `http://localhost:8545`.
2. Go to `truffle.js` file and check that port should be `8545`.
3. Now Migrate the Smart Contract using `truffle migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

The contract name should not be the same as the function name.